# WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin - custom invoicing period

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

So, I've WooCommerce with WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin - by WooCommerce. Now, I've daily subscription, everything works fine. User gets subscription, and is getting invoice each and every day.

Now, which hook can I use to make it invoice my client every 30 days, or at the last day in a month? So, I want to bill the user only once, and count in all the days that have passed since subscription.

Literally any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the specification of that plugin, I see some options like - subscription every 2nd day etc. Did you check that?

Comment: @Fresz yeah, but that will make it bill every second day once, as in, that's billing interval. I want the one day billing interval, as it is now, but I want client to be charged once a month.

Comment: Every month billing cycle will be charged once a month.? What's the issue in that.?

Comment: @mujuonly Yeah, that's true for montly subscription. I want to charge daily subscription monthly.

Comment: This is apparently not possible.